# How can I retrieve the 'id' key from an object in an API endpoint containing an array, in order to update data using the PUT method in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, endpoint

So I had to use PUT method in react to update a piece of data inside an API. I have the endpoint which leads me here:

```
{
   "pagination": {
                 "sortDirection": "DESC",
                 "totalPages": 1,
                 "pageSize": 25,
                 "currentPage": 1,
                 "totalElements": 17
    },
   "data": [
             {
               "author": "Rudra",
               "country": null,
               "language": "Marathi",
               "link": "https://www.google.com",
               "pages": "250",
               "title": "Test Book",
               "year": "2023",
               "id": 11
             },
             {
               "author": "Bhavik",
               "country": null,
               "language": "Gujarati",
               "link": "",
               "pages": "123",
               "title": "testing",
               "year": "2023",
               "id": 13
              }
         ]
}
```

I want to know if there is any way that I can get the "id" key using API Endpoint? or if is there any way that I can use PUT method with this API. I saw somewhere people using - url/{id} but it doesn't work for me. If I get hold of the "id" key it would be pretty easy to update the data in that object I guess.

I tried different ways of changing the endpoint like url/{id} and url/data[0]/{id} where {id} is 0,1,2 but had no luck with that. Please guide me through this.

Comment: `url/{id}` is something for server to expose and handled.. If this route is not exposed or incorrectly implemented, it won't work

Comment: How are we supposed to be able to tell you how to work with "an API", that we know absolutely nothing whatsoever about? _You_ should be reading the API _documentation_ at this point, to find out.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a database, you should get an id when you fetch the data. i.e, inside of data, there's "id": 11 and "id": 13. You can then attempt something like this

```js
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const url = `https://example.com/api/v1/something/${_id}`;
    try {
      axios.put(url, <react state with the values>)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
      throw error;
    }
  }
```